# Register (for dependency injection) a generic abstract class that imprements a generic interface in Program.cs

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to create a database with translation tables for multiple languages and in order to have reusable components, I create abstract classes and interfaces for my entities. I have previously used dependency injection for my AutoMapper and DBContext and registered the classes that needed them like that:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CarService>();
```

but now the classes that in need my dependency injection look like this:

```
public abstract class EntityWithTranslatableDetails<TTranslatedEntity, TTranslatableDetails>  : 
    IEntityWithTranslatableDetails<TTranslatedEntity, TTranslatableDetails> 
    where TTranslatableDetails : ITranslatableDetails 
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public EntityWithTranslatableDetails()
    {

    }
    public EntityWithTranslatableDetails(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

and also like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<TEntity, TTranslatableDetails, TTranslatedEntity>
        : IEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository<TEntity, TTranslatableDetails, TTranslatedEntity>
        where TEntity : EntWithTransFields<TTranslatedEntity, TTranslatableDetails>
        where TTranslatableDetails : TranslatableDetails
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public BaseEntityWithTranslatableFieldsRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

and when I try registering them in Program.cs I either get a null reference error or the build fails. I have tried registering the first example (AutoMapper) like this:

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEntityWithTranslatableDetails<GetCarDTO, CarTranslatableDetails>,
 EntityWithTranslatableDetails<GetCarDTO, CarTranslatableDetails>>();
```

and the response I get is:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'TranslationTableTry.TranslationAbstractions.NonTranslatableDetails.EntityWithTranslatableDetails`2[TranslationTableTry.DTOs.CarDTOs.GetCarDTO,TranslationTableTry.Models.Car.CarTranslatableDetails]' for service type 'TranslationTableTry.TranslationAbstractions.NonTranslatableDetails.IEntityWithTranslatableDetails`2[TranslationTableTry.DTOs.CarDTOs.GetCarDTO,TranslationTableTry.Models.Car.CarTranslatableDetails]'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it asks you to give a concrete instance of the abstract class (or interface).

In your example, you want to register:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEntityWithTranslatableDetails<GetCarDTO, CarTranslatableDetails>,
 EntityWithTranslatableDetails<GetCarDTO, CarTranslatableDetails>>();
```

But for this to work, `EntityWithTranslatableDetails` should be a concrete class, not an abstract one, in order to be instantiate.